# Newest Tex Live Updates introduce vertical space above varwidth

Tags: spacing, varwidth

After updating all packages in Tex Live to the newest version, I have issues with the spacing produced by `varwidth`. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
Minipage behavior:
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
    minipage
\end{minipage}

Varwidth behavior:
\begin{varwidth}[t]{10cm}
    varwidth
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

I'd expect the two outputs to have the same spacing. After the update, however, my output looks like this:

[image: example output]

Is this a newly introduced bug, or do I need to use `varwidth` differently?

Comment: newly introduced feature. (tl2020 version keeps them in line, looking.....)

Comment: Seems to be fixed with the newest updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varwidth must be adapted to the new paragraph hooks. They add an additional glue at the top which it should remove in its processing.

Until there is a real fix you can try this work-around

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@vwid@sift{\skip@\lastskip\unskip}{\skip@\lastskip\unskip\unskip}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Minipage behavior:
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
    minipage
\end{minipage}

Varwidth behavior:
\begin{varwidth}[t]{10cm}
    varwidth
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]