# Tabto introduces vertical space inside varwidth

Tags: spacing, varwidth, tabto

Using the newest packages in TeX Live, the `\tabto` command introduces a slight vertical space when used inside a `varwidth` environment. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,tabto}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{5cm}
    $-$\tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}$-$
\end{varwidth}

$-$\tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}$-$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: MWE output]

I suspect that this is somehow related to the issue discussed here: [Newest Tex Live Updates introduce vertical space above varwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600349/123920)

Did the fix to that issue introduce this quirk?

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem, using your MWE.  But I am not using TeXLive, either.

Comment: This should be fixed at the next firstaid update (next day or so) but you can use the code here between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/586#issuecomment-862296238

Comment: The fix you refer to didn't introduce this behaviour but as issue 586 notes it wasn't quite complete enough fix, but the code in the issue comment appears to work for this example.